# How do I replace letters in text using a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
Letters = {'a': 'z', 'b': 'q', 'm':'j'}
```

I also have a block of random text.

How do I get replace the letters in my text with the letter from the dictionary. So switch 'a' to 'z' and 'b' to 'q'.

What I've done so far is returning the wrong output and I can't think of any other way:

```
splitter = text.split()
res = " ".join(Letters.get(i,i) for i  in text.split())
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over the words in `text`, not over the letters in the words.

There's no need to use `text.split()`. Just iterate over `text` itself to get the letters. And then join them using an empty string.

```
res = "".join(Letters.get(i,i) for i  in text)
```

Answer (score 1):

What we can do is loop through each character in the string and add either the new character or the original character if the new character is not found.

```py
text = "my text ba"
letters = {'a': 'z', 'b': 'q', 'm': 'j'}
result = ""

for letter in text: # For each letter in our string,
    result += letters.get(letter, letter) # Either get a new letter, or use the original letter if it is not found.
```

If you want, you can also do this with a one-liner!

```py
text = "my text ba"
letters = {'a': 'z', 'b': 'q', 'm': 'j'}
result = "".join(letters.get(letter, letter) for letter in text)
```

This is a bit confusing, so to break it down, `for letter in text`, we `get` either the new `letter`, or we use the (default) original `letter`.

You can see the documentation for the `dict.get` method [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: Why do you need the `if` statement? That's what `Letters.get(i, i)` does.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, really? Well, I never knew that bit of python magic!

Answer (score 1):

```
translation_table = str.maketrans({'a': 'z', 'b': 'q', 'm':'j'})
translated = your_text.translate(translation_table)
```

This is concise and fast